# Boostrap navbar doesn't adjust width well

Tags: html, css

I dont't know why incrementing the width on my navbar the incrementation only occur on the right side of the bar, for example, this is my html of my bar:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">                  
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">  
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Free shipping over $50</a>
                </li>
            </ul>              
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">  
                <li>
                    <a class ="lita" href="#about">Be part of THE CIRLCE</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#services">JOIN </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#contact">LOGIN</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Using this css:

```
#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1{
background-color: #fde6dc;
padding: 2px 40px;
width: 100%;
}
```

The result is this one:

http://postimg.org/image/m7qu1vz45/full/

But, if I move the width by 150%, this happen:

http://postimg.org/image/60px3u3m9/full/

Why is this happening? Why it doesn't adjust keeping the ratio, if I put a margin It kind of resolve the problem, but when I re-size the screen it doesn't work.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: You should scroll to right to view the `float:right` div. If you increase the width more than 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this for navbar,

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li>
                    <a href="#">Free shipping over $50</a>
                </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li>
                    <a class ="lita" href="#about">Be part of THE CIRLCE</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#services">JOIN </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#contact">LOGIN</a>
                </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```